# C# executenonquery does not update database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

The following code works, i get the messagebox saying the product has been updated, however no changes are made in the database.

This was copied and pasted from another method that works in the same database, and that method works fine.

```
    private void btnProductSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtProductName.Text != "")
        {
            var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to save changes to this product?", "Confirm Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SqlConnection con = null;
                con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PVAdmin.Properties.Settings.PricerConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                string sql2 = "UPDATE Products SET productName = @productName WHERE productID = @productID";

                SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
                myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", txtProductName.Text);
                myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", lblProductID.Text);

                con.Open();
                myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Product saved.");
                this.LoadProduct((int)cboProductSelect.SelectedValue);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No changes were saved.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this before and what it ends up being is the sql engine appears to update itself with itself.  Since your @parm is the same as the column, sql is saying update me with me.

To fix, try SLIGHTLY renaming your parameters such as

```
UPDATE Products SET productName = @pProductName WHERE productID = @pPproductID";
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pProductName", txtProductName.Text);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pProductID", lblProductID.Text);
```

this way, SQL does not have a column "pProductName" and will in-fact go to the parameter... likewise with "pProductID".  Very subtle, but is probably exactly what you are encountering.  Also, which database are you connecting to. Different engines use different token character for parameter passing... "?", "@", ":" as just a few I know of...

Comment: I am using Sql Server.  I tried this, but the results are the same.  This is driving me insane because it works fine in another method, just not this one.

Comment: @Katp00p, try adding an int RowsUpdated = cmd.executenonquery... and then messagebox the rowsUpdated value.  Is it coming back with one as expected or zero records.

Comment: I figured out the problem... had nothing to do with the query, it was the value stored in lblProductID.  Thank you for your help, I will delete this question so that it doesn't confuse people in the future.